# jdbc error Parameter index out of range (2 > number of parameters, which is 1)

Tags: java, jdbc

I wrote following java method and when I call it, gives me the error

```
Parameter index out of range (2 > number of parameters, which is 1).
```

it is giving error at line preparedStatement.setInt(2,p);

```
for(int t=0;t<2 & exit;t++){
    sql="SELECT allocationProb FROM trial.teacherallocation where TeacherID=?;";
                    preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(sql);
                    preparedStatement.setString(1,var1[t]);
                    ResultSet rs3=preparedStatement.executeQuery();
                    rs3.next();
                    int allocationProb=rs3.getInt(1);
                    rs3.close();
                    System.out.println("INSIDE");
                    int p=0;
                    if(allocationProb==0){ 
                        p=1;
                     sql="UPDATE `trial`.`teacherallocation` SET `AllocationSub1`=?,` allocationProb`=? WHERE `TeacherID`=?;";
                     preparedStatement.setString(1,str1);
                     preparedStatement.setInt(2,p);
                     preparedStatement.setString(3,var1[t]);
                     preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
                    }
}
```

Comment: The prepared statement you are using is for the SQL `sql="SELECT allocationProb FROM trial.teacherallocation where TeacherID=?;";` which only has one parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Although you change your `sql` variable

```
sql="UPDATE `trial`.`teacherallocation` SET `AllocationSub1`=?,` allocationProb`=? WHERE `TeacherID`=?;";
```

you don't create a new `PreparedStatement` with it. So when you call

```
preparedStatement.setString(1,str1);
preparedStatement.setInt(2,p);
preparedStatement.setString(3,var1[t]);
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

you're calling it on the SQL

```
sql="SELECT allocationProb FROM trial.teacherallocation where TeacherID=?;";
```

which only has 1 parameter and will throw an exception if you try to add more.

You need to create a new or reassign a `PreparedStatement` object before those lines.

```
sql="UPDATE `trial`.`teacherallocation` SET `AllocationSub1`=?,` allocationProb`=? WHERE `TeacherID`=?;";
preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(sql);
preparedStatement.setString(1,str1);
preparedStatement.setInt(2,p);
preparedStatement.setString(3,var1[t]);
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Also you should close all jdbc connections when you are done with them.

`preparedStatement.close();`

Comment: If any of the answers were helpful, you can upvote them and/or accept one.

Comment: @user2094670: if you think Sotirios' answer is helpful i suggest you should accept and upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

You are using same prepared statement for two different SQL statements. And No of parameters is different as well. That's why you are getting this error.

Try following

if(allocationProb==0){ 
p=1;
 preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(sql);

Hope it helps